# Find files and pack them using a shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to find all files which size is higher than $1 (parameter) and zip them using a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -size +$1c = $files
tar -xf $files
```

But I think this isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `find` command works the way you want you just need to change your bash syntax a bit. Also your tar command is extracting `-x`.

```
files=$(find ./ -type f -size +$1c)
#fix names in case there are spaces. Insert \ to escape spaces
goodNames="${files// /\\ }"
tar -czf bigfiles.tar.gz $goodNames
```

Comment: This will break if any of the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: Good catch. Edited to avoid that problem